# How to print the binary value(memory) between two address in gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb

For example, I have 2 address, add1 `0x7fffeb26dfc0` and add2 `0x7fffeb26e000`

add2 - add1 is always 64.

I wound like to know the binary value of the memory area between add1 and add2

like 0101001.....10101 (count: 512)

Is there any convenient way to do it?

I'm currently doing following:

```
x 0x7fffeb26dfc0
x 0x7fffeb26dfc1
x 0x7fffeb26dfc2
...
x 0x7fffeb26e000
```

Comment: http://www.os4coding.net/forum/using-gdb-do-hex-dump-memory

Comment: Try `x/64tb 0x7fffeb26dfc0` if you want to see it byte-by-byte, or `x/8tg 0x7fffeb26dfc0` if you want to see 8-byte integers (in whatever byte ordering your platform has). Is that what you want, or do you want a string of 512 0's and 1's?